# PHP object operator building string within foreach?

Tags: php, class, object

I am trying to build an object that will hold multiple objects based of iterating through an array:

```
<?php
$final_object = new stdClass();

$array = ['one','two'];

$temp_str = '';
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $temp_str .= $value . '->';
}

$temp_str = rtrim($temp_str, '->');

$final_object->$temp_str = 999;

print_r($final_object);
exit;
```

As you can guess, the parser treats '->' as a string literal and not a PHP object operator.

Is what I am attempting to do possible?

Eventually, I want to build a json string after json_encoding to: {"one":{"two": 999}}

Comment: Yes, it is possible to "build an object that will hold multiple objects based of iterating through an array", as you asked. But it is not clear what you're trying to do with this code. It seems that your question is more about how to do something with `->`. What are you trying to do with that? What should the final result look like?

Comment: BTW: The loop could be replaced with `$temp_str = join('->', $array)`.

Comment: I am merely trying to build a json string after json_encoding to:
{"one":{"two": 999}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a reference of the object during the loop and assign your value at the end:

```
$final_object = new stdClass();

$array = ['one','two'];

$ref = $final_object ;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $ref->$value = new stdClass() ;
    $ref = &$ref->$value ; // keep reference of last object
}
$ref = 999; // change last reference to your value

print_r($final_object);
```

Outputs:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [one] => stdClass Object
        (
            [two] => 999
        )
)
```

You could do the same using arrays:

```
$array = ['one','two'];
$final_object = [];
$ref =& $final_object;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $ref[$value] = [];
    $ref =& $ref[$value];
}
$ref=999;
echo json_encode($final_object);
```

Outputs:

```
{"one":{"two":999}}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the second time =)